# Canvas Linear Gradient

Tags: javascript, canvas, linear-gradients

I wanna add my linear gradient on my cubic Curve while changing its position while moving my mouse. But somehow it won't work. If i stop changing its position and fix it on my screen it works.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  ctx.fillStyle = "#CCC";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  //var prev = {};
  var mouse = {};

  window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    //prev.x = mouse.x;
    //prev.y = mouse.y;

    mouse.x = e.pageX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY;
  });

  function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#CCC";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(50, 50, 150, 150);
    grad.addColorStop(0, "yellow");
    grad.addColorStop(0.5, "white");
    grad.addColorStop(1, "orange");

    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.strokeStyle = grad;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo((canvas.width / 2), (canvas.height / 2));

    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(((canvas.width / 2) - 100), (canvas.height / 2 + 100), (mouse.x), (mouse.y));
    ctx.stroke()
  };

  window.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I remove it from the DOMContentLoaded event function it works fine in this jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wboq6bsk/

```
  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  canvas.id= 'test'
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  ctx.fillStyle = "#CCC";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  var mouse = {};

  window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){

    mouse.x = e.pageX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY;
  });

  function draw(){
   console.log('dra');
    ctx.fillStyle = "#CCC";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(50, 50, 150, 150);
    grad.addColorStop(0, "yellow");
    grad.addColorStop(0.5, "white");
    grad.addColorStop(1, "orange");

    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.strokeStyle = grad;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo((canvas.width/2), (canvas.height/2));

    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(((canvas.width/2)-100), (canvas.height/2+100), (mouse.x), (mouse.y));
    ctx.stroke()
  }

  window.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
```

Unless you mean your gradient it not moving with the curve, but right now this has normal behavior. You can probably get the gradient to move too by passing in mouse positions while creating the gradient on each draw.

Comment: Do u know why it works when removing the DOMContentLoaded? It often appears code is not working when i wont add it. What do u mean by passing mouse positions? Where do i have to pass them?

Comment: Haven't had the time to test your solution as a local project so I used fiddle which I believe is going to insert the script at the right time without the need on DOMContentLoaded. (Please correct me on this). Try adding your scripts tag after your HTML content at the end of  body and see if you still need DOMContentLoaded.

Comment: A *linear* gradient needs a startpoint and an endpoint. These are the numbers you give your createLinearGradient method. If you give the same startpoint and endpoint as your curve the gradient should follow your mouse. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient